# Entity Framework returns stale data when selecting the whole entity but up to date when selecting just a field

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

My Entity Framework backed project returns stale data when selecting the whole entity but the data is up to date when selecting just a field from the entity.

Here are the steps:

1. **Query via EF/LINQ:**

   ```
   var e  = context.myEntity.First(x=>x.ID==ID);
   string n = context.myEntity.Where(x=>x.ID==ID).Select(x=>x.Name).First();
   ```
2. **Update the Name field in the DB via SQL directly**
3. **Then Query again via EF/LINQ:**

   ```
   var e  = context.myEntity.First(x=>x.ID==ID);
   string n = context.myEntity.Where(x=>x.ID==ID).Select(x=>x.Name).First();
   ```

`e.Name` is the previous value but `n` is up to date.

We are re-using the same context between calls.

Using the SQL profiler, I can confirm that even when the data is stale the SQL query from EF occurs.

What can cause this?

Comment: What `MergeOption` are you using?

Comment: Not explicitly setting it, so it must be the default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is cached in the Context. Ideally your context should have a short lifetime (a unit of work, for example) to prevent this behaviour becoming a problem, but if you need to force an update from the database, set the MergeOption to OverwriteChanges

```
context.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges
```

Comment: `OverwriteChanges` is probably not the best option in the case of @Matt, where he is keeping the context open.

Comment: That's why I say he shouldn't. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are using the default context merge option `MergeOption.AppendOnly`. This option basically tells the underlying context structure to never replace existing entities with new values coming in from a datasource query.

You have other options though, I suggested reading the below and seeing if one of the other options better fits the scenario you desire.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.mergeoption.aspx

It sounds like your best option might be `MergeOption.PreserveChanges`